# Why is there a foreign key mismatch error in this code?

Tags: c#, sqlite, system.data.sqlite

I use C# with System.Data.SQLite library and I got a foreign key mismatch error.
I created three tables:

```
Com.CommandText = @"create table Projekt ([ProjectID] Integer NOT NULL Primary key, [Projektname] varchar(360),[ProjektEd] DATETIME, [ProjektLSD] Datetime, [ProjektLD] Datetime);";
Com.ExecuteNonQuery();
Com.CommandText= "create table Template ([TemplateID] Integer NOT NULL Primary key,[Templatename] varchar(360),[TemplateEd] Datetime, [TemplateLSD] Datetime,[TemplateLD] Datetime);";
Com.ExecuteNonQuery();
Com.CommandText = "create table Messung ([MessungID] Integer Not Null Primary Key, [Messungname] varchar(360), [MessungEd] Datetime, [MessungLSD] Datetime, [MessungLD] Datetime, [ProjektID] Integer, [TemplateID] Integer,FOREIGN KEY(ProjektID) REFERENCES Projekt(ProjektID), Foreign Key (TemplateID) References Template(TemplateID)); ";
Com.ExecuteNonQuery();
```

After that I insert
this creates my first entry in the "Projekt" table:

```
Insert into projekt (Projektname, ProjektEd,ProjektLSD, ProjektLD) values ('Messung_Win_3', '2016-06-16 14:47:00','2016-06-27 14:47:00', '2016-07-14 11:12:00');
```

while this creates my fourth entry (I have another three inserts before this one) in the table "Template":

```
Insert into Template (Templatename, TemplateEd, TemplateLSD, TemplateLD) values('Messung_Win_3', '2016-05-19 15:13:00','2016-06-27 14:47:00', '2016-07-14 11:12:00');
```

So now to the question:
Why does this command have a foreign key mismatch error?

```
Com.CommandText = "Insert into Messung (Messungname, MessungEd, ProjektID, TemplateID) values ('Board2ROI3','2016-06-16 14:47:00',1,4);";
```

I testet it via SQLFiddle with the SQLite (SQL.js). Link is here: http://sqlfiddle.com/

There it worked perfectly fine but in C# it gets this error.

I hope you can help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You spelled your FK projectId wrong

```
Com.CommandText = @"create table Projekt ([**ProjectID**] Integer NOT NULL Primary key, [Projektname] varchar(360),[ProjektEd] DATETIME, [ProjektLSD] Datetime, [ProjektLD] Datetime);";


Com.CommandText = "create table Messung ([MessungID] Integer Not Null Primary Key, [Messungname] varchar(360), [MessungEd] Datetime, [MessungLSD] Datetime, [MessungLD] Datetime, [ProjektID] Integer, [TemplateID] Integer,FOREIGN KEY(ProjektID) REFERENCES Projekt(**ProjektID**), Foreign Key (TemplateID) References Template(TemplateID)); ";
```